# .NET swagger authorization (jwt) without Bearer prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have my own authorization middleware that reads jwt and get token from authorization header. Using swagger authorization :

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
```

i have always header like this: "Authorization: Bearer ".

I wonder if there is possibility to disable this 'Bearer' prefix and sending headers in:
Authorization:  form?

Comment: "Bearer" is the name of the authentication scheme and is usually expected to be there, e.g. MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization. Why do you need to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey` instead of `.Http`:

```cs
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
```

This defines the `Authorization: VALUE` header without any value prefixes.

Remember to also add security requirements:

```cs
option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "ApiKey" }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thansk! That works but remember to add security requirements for ApiKey - it is mandatory